# ag-grid with pinned column runneth over

Tags: ag-grid

Adding pinned:'left' in the columnDefs, makes the grid height increase.

```
var columnDefs = [
       { headerName: "Company", field: "cname", pinned: 'left' },
       .....
```

Three of the divs keep their height growing by 2px constantly:

[image]

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksutine/kgovc9yv/5/).

Once you open it, see that the bottom of the grid keeps moving down. How to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I used a temporary solution by specifying a hard-coded height instead of the 100%.

Comment: Thank you Niels, I was doing it too, and then realized that if I don't set css for the height at all, then it works. So, instead of style="height: 100%; max-width:713px;" I'm using style="max-width:713px;".

Answer (score 0):

Meet this bug too,and can't resolve it by "don't set css for height at all".
But I found it related to the theme styles. It's only happend to the ag-fresh theme.
Change themes will make it work.
Otherwise we can cover the style of .ag-body set the border-top to none.

```
.ag-body { border-top: none; }
```

Comment: Themes ag-blue and ag-dark are having the same issue. Removing the class for the theme stops the bottom border, but then all styles should be done manually... Tried .ag-body { border-top: none; } - didn't fix the issue.